# I want to build a crime index and political instability index based in news stories

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I have this side project where I crawl the local news websites in my country and want to build a crime index and political instability index.
I have already covered the information retrieval part of the project. My plan is to do:

- Unsupervised topic extraction.
- Near duplicates detection.
- Supervised classification and incident level (crime/political - high/medium/low).

I will use python and sklearn and have already research the algorithms that I can use for those tasks. I think 2. could give me a relevancy factor of a story: the more news papers publish about an story or topic the more relevant for that day.

My next step is to build the monthly, weekly and daily index (nation-wide and per cities) based on the features that I have, and I'm a little lost here as the "instability sensitivity" might increase to the time. I mean, the index from the major instability incident of the last year could be less than the index for this year. Also if to use fixed scale 0-100 or not.

Later I would like to be able to predict incidents based on this, e.g. whether the succession of events in the last weeks are leading to a major incident. But for now I will be happy with getting the classification working and building the index model.

I would appreciate any pointer to a paper, relevant readings or thoughts.
Thanks.

PD: Sorry if the question does not belong here.

**UPDATE**: I haven't yet "make it", but recently there was a news about a group of scientists that are working in a system to [predict the events using news archives](http://gigaom.com/2013/02/01/how-two-scientists-are-using-the-new-york-times-archives-to-predict-the-future/) and released a relevant paper [Mining the Web to Predict Future Events](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/horvitz/future_news_wsdm.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: For technical part (the tools) I would recommend two books as good staring point both fro O'Reiley: Collective Intelligence (with Python code), Machine Learning ( with R code ) ...tey capture topics related with yours. Next step might be Manning website...
For methodological part I would recommend Semantic Web group on LinkedIn.

Comment: Super much like this question. Keep us updated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider variations on the GINI score.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiniCoefficient.html

It is normalized, and its output ranges from 0 to 1.

EDIT:

Why GINI is "cool" or at least potentially appropriate:

It is a measure of inequality or inequity.  It is used as a scale free measure to characterize the heterogeneity of scale-free networks, including infinite and random networks.  It is useful in building CART trees because it is the measure of splitting power of a particular data-split.

Because of its range:

- there is less roundoff errors.  Ranges far away from 1.0 tend to suffer numeric issues.
- it is human readable, and more human accessible.  Humans have a more concrete grasp of ones of objects than they do of billions.

Because it is normalized:

- comparisons of scores are meaningful, a 0.9 in one country means the same level of relative non-uniformity as a 0.9 in any other country.
- It is normalized against the Lorenz curve for perfect uniformity therefore the values are relevant indicators of the relationship of the distribution of values of interest to the Lorenz curve.

References:

- [1] http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SI.POV.GINI
- [2] http://research3.bus.wisc.edu/file.php/129/Papers/Gini27April2011.pdf
- [3] http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#giniimp
- [4] http://www2.unine.ch/files/content/sites/imi/files/shared/documents/papers/Gini_index_fulltext.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the site, @EngrStudent. Would you mind saying a little more about the GINI coefficient, & why it's the right answer here? Since you're new here & starting to contribute, you might want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which contains a lot of info about the site.